# Twilio Message - Emojis are replaced with "?" in the actual message

Tags: twilio

I am using twilio to send sms messages through my Java Application.

And when I am sending emojis, emoji is being replaced with ? in the actual message I am getting.

I wasn't able to figure out what is the issue.

Any inputs about this error could be really helpful.

I read in twilio website that emoji's delivery is not guarateed. But I tested with multiple carriers. And I didn't get the emoji in not even one. Even if anyone aware of the list of carriers that it could support, it will be great.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Emoji support has not been standardised across carriers, as a result we cannot guarantee support for Emoji across all of them. We will do the best we can to ensure the emoji in your message is delivered to your mobile carrier, but if they don't understand that emoji, they will usually replace it with gibberish.

Chances are that you will see some carriers show emoji and some not.

Comment: I tested it with three different carriers. i didn't get the correct message even in one. So, I thought may be there is a configuration issue. Is there any configuration or something i should do for that?

Comment: And I tested it by sending "♕ " symbol through twilio from my application. It is been replaced with some other character. But I have seen one application which uses twilio to send all the symbols of chess game and I am receiving it correctly. So, how can it not deliver the same symbol to the same mobile number until and unless there is configuration issue I am missing.

Comment: Hi, in that case I would suggest opening up a ticket with https://www.twilio.com/help and provide them with both `from` phone numbers and they will be able to check what is being sent by them and tell you what is going on. Most likely it's to do with the encoding of the string you're passing in.

Comment: Please mark the question as answered if you're satisfied with the answer. Thanks

Comment: Ok, until all carriers can support, where can we find a list of supported emoji?

Comment: I have the same problem. Anyone found any solution?